# Rewriting a URL with GET Parameters to .pdf

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have dynamic URLs in WordPress like this:

```
https://example.com/category/post-title/?format=pdf

https://example.com/category2/post-title2/?format=pdf
```

And I want them to be rewritten to:

```
https://example.com/category/post-title.pdf

https://example.com/category2/post-title2.pdf
```

How do I do this with htaccess?

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^.(.*) /?format=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)\.pdf$ /$1/$2?format=pdf [L]
```

This will internally map a request for `/folder/foobar.pdf` to `/folder/foobar?format=pdf` . Just remember to put this code at the top of your htaccess or before WordPress rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you!
I can't get it to work. The /folder is a category for posts and it changes with the category name.

I tried this and entered the category name:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)\.pdf$ /category-name/$1/?format=pdf [L]`

Comment: @Uklove I have edited the code on my answer. There was a typo that has been fixed as well. Please try the updated version now.

Comment: I tried everything and it did not work until I wrote the full path `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)\.pdf$ https://example.com/$1/$2/?format=pdf [L]` . Maybe this is server specific, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.